# How to add option menu in fragment with new menuprovider

Tags: android, android-fragments

How do i add options menu on fragment with the new Menu Provider, specifically searchview menu?

```
override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.explore, menu)
}

override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (menuItem.itemId) {
        R.id.btn_search_menu -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemSelected: Clicked")
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

i tried using this code but the menu didn't get inflated

Comment: So where do you call `addMenuProvider`?

Comment: on fragment, but i dont call add menu provider, i inherit from it with my fragment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As seen in the [Activity `1.4.0-alpha01` release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.4.0-alpha01) (where the `MenuProvider` API was added), creating a `MenuProvider` is only half of the problem - you then need to call `addMenuProvider` on a `MenuHost` like your activity:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // The usage of an interface lets you inject your own implementation
    val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
  
    // Add the MenuProvider to the MenuHost
    menuHost.addMenuProvider(
      this, // your Fragment implements MenuProvider, so we use this here
      viewLifecycleOwner, // Only show the Menu when your Fragment's View exists
      Lifecycle.State.RESUMED // And when the Fragment is RESUMED
    )
}
```